# Binding converter as inner class?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a UserControl that uses a binding converter. I've made the converter an inner class of

```
public partial class MyPanel : UserControl
{
    public class CornerRadiusConverter : IValueConverter
    {
```

How do I reference the Converter class from the XAML? The following does not work:

```
<controls:MyPanel.CornerRadiusConverter x:Key="CornerRadiusConverter" />
```

It gives this error:

> The tag
>   'LensPanel.CornerRadiusConverter' does
>   not exist in XML namespace
>   'clr-namespace:MyApp.Windows.Controls'

Comment: Just use a normal class!

Comment: @SergeyAldoukhov: Why? That suggestion is not helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was thinking about this problem again, and I came up with something similar to Dennis's solution : create a "proxy" converter class, with a Type property, which will create the instance of the actual converter and delegate the conversion to it.

```
public class Converter : IValueConverter
{
    private Type _type = null;
    public Type Type
    {
        get { return _type; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _type)
            {
                if (value.GetInterface("IValueConverter") != null)
                {
                    _type = value;
                    _converter = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException(
                        string.Format("Type {0} doesn't implement IValueConverter", value.FullName),
                        "value");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private IValueConverter _converter = null;
    private void CreateConverter()
    {
        if (_converter == null)
        {
            if (_type != null)
            {
                _converter = Activator.CreateInstance(_type) as IValueConverter;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Converter type is not defined");
            }
        }
    }

    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        CreateConverter();
        return _converter.Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        CreateConverter();
        return _converter.ConvertBack(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

You use it like that :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <my:Converter x:Key="CornerRadiusConverter" Type="{x:Type controls:MyPanel+CornerRadiusConverter}"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be possible. A few months ago I wrote a markup extension to create the converter for you inline. It keeps a dictionary of weak references so that you don't create multiple instances of the same converter. Handles creating converters with different arguments too.

In XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Converter={NamespaceForMarkupExt:InlineConverter {x:Type NamespaceForConverter:ConverterType}}}"/>
```

C#:

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(IValueConverter))]
public class InlineConverterExtension : MarkupExtension
{
  static Dictionary<string, WeakReference> s_WeakReferenceLookup;

  Type m_ConverterType;
  object[] m_Arguments;

  static InlineConverterExtension()
  {
    s_WeakReferenceLookup = new Dictionary<string, WeakReference>();
  }

  public InlineConverterExtension()
  {
  }

  public InlineConverterExtension(Type converterType)
  {
    m_ConverterType = converterType;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// The type of the converter to create
  /// </summary>
  /// <value>The type of the converter.</value>
  public Type ConverterType
  {
    get { return m_ConverterType; }
    set { m_ConverterType = value; }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// The optional arguments for the converter's constructor.
  /// </summary>
  /// <value>The argumments.</value>
  public object[] Arguments
  {
    get { return m_Arguments; }
    set { m_Arguments = value; }
  }

  public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
  {
    IProvideValueTarget target = (IProvideValueTarget)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));

    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = target.TargetProperty as PropertyInfo;

    if (!propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IValueConverter)))
      throw new NotSupportedException("Property '" + propertyInfo.Name + "' is not assignable from IValueConverter.");

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(m_ConverterType != null, "ConverterType is has not been set, ConverterType{x:Type converterType}");

    try
    {
      string key = m_ConverterType.ToString();

      if (m_Arguments != null)
      {
        List<string> args = new List<string>();
        foreach (object obj in m_Arguments)
          args.Add(obj.ToString());

        key = String.Concat(key, "_", String.Join("|", args.ToArray()));
      }

      WeakReference wr = null;
      if (s_WeakReferenceLookup.TryGetValue(key, out wr))
      {
        if (wr.IsAlive)
          return wr.Target;
        else
          s_WeakReferenceLookup.Remove(key);
      }

      object converter = (m_Arguments == null) ? Activator.CreateInstance(m_ConverterType) : Activator.CreateInstance(m_ConverterType, m_Arguments);
      s_WeakReferenceLookup.Add(key, new WeakReference(converter));

      return converter;
    }
    catch(MissingMethodException)
    {
      // constructor for the converter does not exist!
      throw;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Cool idea ! I'm a big fan of custom markup extensions myself ;)

Answer (score -3):

What I do is:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
    <Converters:BooleanNotConverter x:Key="BooleanNotConverter"/>
   </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

And then in the control

```
  <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=BoolProperty, Converter={StaticResource BooleanNotConverter} />
```

Comment: It doesn't solve Robert's problem, which is that his converter class is a nested class...