# How to declare a resource from a private inner class in WPF?

Tags: wpf, private, converters, inner-classes

I'm trying to declare a resource in a WPF UserControl, and I'd like the resource to be an instance of a private inner class. How do I do this?

XAML:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl 
{
    private class MyConverter : IValueConverter 
    {
        // convertion code...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it if the class is private, you could make it internal instead

Regarding the declaration of an inner class in XAML, you should have a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863180/binding-converter-as-inner-class/)