# local resource added doesn't show up in WPF page

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this simple `WPF` page in which I am adding a local resource, which has its definition in Page's backend file.

```
<Page x:Class="WindowsSampleApplication.ValueConverter"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WindowsSampleApplication"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    Title="ValueConverter">
    <Page.Resources>
        <local:YesNoToBooleanConverter x:Key="YesNoToBooleanConverter" />
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <TextBox Name="txtValue" />
            <WrapPanel Margin="0,10">
                <TextBlock Text="Current value is: " />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=txtValue, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource YesNoToBooleanConverter}}"></TextBlock>
            </WrapPanel>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=txtValue, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource YesNoToBooleanConverter}}" Content="Yes" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

and this is the backend file for `Page`

```
namespace WindowsSampleApplication
{
    public partial class ValueConverter : Page
    {
        public ValueConverter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public class YesNoToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                switch (value.ToString().ToLower())
                {
                    case "yes":
                        return true;
                    case "no":
                        return false;
                }
                return false;
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                if (value is bool)
                {
                    if ((bool)value == true)
                        return "yes";
                    else
                        return "no";
                }
                return "no";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have properly included namespace `WindowsSampleApplication` in `Page` level and the same namespace has definition for my resource. But am getting below `error` when added that `local resource`

[image: Error Image]

I've just started with `WPF` tutorials from **[here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/)** but only thing I was trying rather than following tutorial was I added a **Page** instead of **Window** since I have created a `Window` already with earlier demos given there and hopefully I have converted everything that a **Page** needs to have instead of **Window**. Anyone have idea on how to resolve this issue?

**UPDATE**

I've also tried wrapping `<local..../>` withing `<ResourceDictionary>` as I ready it in SO, but wasn't of much use and error still remained as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think yout problem is that you have nested your converter inside `ValueConverter` page.

[EDIT]

There is no possibility of instantiate nested classes so the only option will be to declare converter class directly in `WindowsSampleApplication` namespace.

**Updated code**

```
namespace WindowsSampleApplication
{
    public partial class ValueConverter : Page
    {
        public ValueConverter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //Removed from here
    }
    public class YesNoToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            switch (value.ToString().ToLower())
            {
                case "yes":
                case "oui":
                    return true;
                case "no":
                case "non":
                    return false;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is bool)
            {
                if ((bool)value == true)
                    return "yes";
                else
                    return "no";
            }
            return "no";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well then it says **Nested Properties are not supported**.. :(

Comment: Ahh, my fault! You cannot use nested classes at all. Just try to declare converter directly inside a WindowsSampleApplication namespace. That should do, I'll modify my answer

Comment: Buddy.. That is the actual answer.. I misplaced converter class inside `ValueConverter` by oversight. They have given properly in **DEMO**. It should actually be outside.. Just now I found it too.. Please update the answer and I shall accept it... :) Thanks for your time..

Comment: Updated your answer to be bit detailed.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Since it looks like you are just trying out WPF, and you put the converter in the codebehind for no special reason, I would recommend the usual way for creating converters:

Create a new directory *Converters* in your WindowsSampleApplication project. Then add a new class file for each converter...

Now you know where to find your converters, and can easily reuse them.

PS: It's possible to put the converter in the codebehind as a nested class, but you should have a really good reason to do it. ([Binding converter as inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863180/binding-converter-as-inner-class))

Comment: Yea thank you.. Well issue was something different.. Thanks for showing up with new idea.. :) +1 for that..

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `YesNoToBooleanConverter` directly in the namespace.
From MSDN: XAML and Custom Classes for WPF

Your custom class must be public and support a default (parameterless) public constructor. (See following section for notes regarding structures.)
Your custom class must not be a nested class. Nested classes and the "dot" in their general CLR usage syntax interfere with other WPF and/or XAML features such as attached properties.

Link:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753379(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your time.. I would suggest to make the explanations short and sweet i.e. getting up with only important points and then providing the source.. :) Anyways.. +1 for your time.. :)