# Cannot set multibinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My multibinding is not working. I get the error: *The name 'MatrixToDataViewConverter' does not exist in the namespace 'clr-NameSpace: myNamespace'* in my xaml (I have marked the line). Why?

xaml

```
 <Window x:Class="myNamespace.PopMeUp"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:app="clr-namespace:myNamespace"
            Title="PopMeUp" Height="300" Width="300">
        <Window.Resources>
            <app:MatrixToDataViewConverter x:Key="MatrixToDataViewConverter"/> <!-- Error here-->
        </Window.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <DataGrid>
                <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MatrixToDataViewConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="ColumnHeaders"/>
                        <Binding Path="RowHeaders"/>
                        <Binding Path="Values"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
            </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
          </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

.cs file:

```
namespace myNamespace    
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for PopMeUp.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PopMeUp : Window
    {
        public PopMeUp(MWArray[] Result, int rows, int columns)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public class MatrixToDataViewConverter : IMultiValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                var myDataTable = new DataTable(); 
                return myDataTable.DefaultView;
            }


            public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does your `ResultPopUp` class implements `IMultiValueConverter`?
Have you tried putting your `MatrixToDataViewConverter` in a seperate file or at least outsite the `ResultPopUp` so that it's reachable?

Comment: Why did you define `MatrixToDataViewConverter` as a nested class?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to take the IMultiValueConverter away from the ResultPopUp class. I've tried to put it in a separate class but it doesn't work, I got the same error. @MightyBadaboom

Comment: Have a look at my answer for further information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that `MatrixToDataViewConverter` is a nested class. Refactor the cs file like this:

```
namespace myNamespace    
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ResultPopUp.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ResultPopUp : Window
    {
        public ResultPopUp(MWArray[] Result, int rows, int columns)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }        
    }

    public class MatrixToDataViewConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var myDataTable = new DataTable(); 
            return myDataTable.DefaultView;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Then perform a `Clean` and `Rebuild` on your solution. Close the XAML designer and reopen it.

Comment: Oh I feel so stupid. Thank you so much! It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

You can not define an `IValueConverter` or `IMultiValueConverter` as a nested class. Just put it in a seperate file or at least outside your `ResultPopUp` class.

For further information have a look at: [Binding converter as inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863180/binding-converter-as-inner-class)

Maybe you have to cleanup and rebuild your solution after the refactoring.